# Control Normal Chrome Window opened some desktop window in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a desktop app that opens a URL in Chrome browser after some authorization in the backend which cannot be controlled. If I open the same link using copy-paste in some other Chrome browser, it does ask for credentials again which is not an ideal case as I have already logged in desktop app. So there are my limitations.

I want to take control to run my automation of an existing browser opened by some other desktop app.

I tried attaching the new web driver to the newly opened browser. tried to find in windowHandles to find required browser. It is opening a new one.

Comment: you can't do that unless the browser was launched in dev-mode and you have it's debug port and/or session id.  You need to know how the desktop app is launching the browser.  Can you include the code the app uses to launch Chrome?  (Selenium does not use a window handle... it uses wire protocol and sessionID)